# I want to calculated by multiplying all of the items of the input array, but except for example i-th item

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, algorithm

as an example

given the following array, `inputArray: [2,3,6,8]`
the result array would be:     `resultArray: [144,96,48,36]`

```
resultArray[0] = inputArray[1] * inputArray[2] * inputArray[3]
resultArray[1] = inputArray[0] * inputArray[2] * inputArray[3]
resultArray[n] = inputArray[0] *...* inputArray[n-1] * inputArray[n+1] *...* inputArray[last]
```

I have written code as follows, but how can I do this calculation with for or another loop.

```
static void multiply()
    {
        int[] inputArray = { 2, 3, 6, 8 };
        int[] resultArray = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(inputArray[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        //for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    resultArray[i] = inputArray[0] * inputArray[i - 1] * inputArray[i + 1];
        //}
        resultArray[0] = inputArray[1] * inputArray[2] * inputArray[3];
        resultArray[1] = inputArray[0] * inputArray[2] * inputArray[3];
        resultArray[2] = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1] * inputArray[3];
        resultArray[3] = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1] * inputArray[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(resultArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not multiply all numbers, and divide that number by the number in the i'th number i the array?

Comment: @Andersnk you should add it as an answer with example

Comment: @Andersnk your method will fail if large numbers are encountered, e.g. `{ 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004 }`.

Comment: @Andersnk, won't work if any value is zero.

Comment: If any provided answers have helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{

    static int GetMulResult(int[] input, int ommitingIndex)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == ommitingIndex)
                continue;

            result *= input[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] inputArray = { 2, 3, 6, 8 };

        int[] result1 = new int[4];


        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
            result1[i] = GetMulResult(inputArray, i);



    }
}
```

PS. I'm afraid that if you are not able to create such a simple algorithm, you won't be able to create more usable algorithms. You should work on that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it using Linq is to use `Aggregate` to get the total product of the values, and then assign the result value equal to the product divided by the input item at the current loop index:

```
static void Multiply()
{
    int[] input = { 2, 3, 6, 8 };
    int[] result = new int[input.Length];

    var product = input.Aggregate((i, j) => i * j);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = product / input[i];
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", input));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

My approach follows the thought line of many. I have used LINQ for simplicity.

```
        int fullProduct = 1;
        List<int> input = new List<int> { 2, 3, 6, 8 };
        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        input.ForEach(v => { fullProduct *= v; });
        input.ForEach(c=>
        {
           result.Add(fullProduct / c);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are just leaving the number whose index you want in resultant array, so you can divide by that number. Below is the code that can help you

```
            int result = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.Length; j++)
                    {
                        result = result * inputArray[j];
                    }

                for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.Length; i++)
                {

                    resultArray[i] = result / inputArray[i];
                }
```

Please accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can just not multiply the value if the indices are the same:

```
private static void multiply()
{
    int[] inputArray = { 2, 3, 6, 8 };
    int[] resultArray = new int[inputArray.Length];

    for ( int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++ )
        Console.Write(inputArray[i] + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();

    for ( int indexInOutput = 0; indexInOutput < resultArray.Length; indexInOutput++ )
    {
        int result = 1;
        for ( int indexInInput = 0; indexInInput < inputArray.Length; indexInInput++ )
        {
            if ( indexInInput != indexInOutput )
                result *= inputArray[indexInInput];
        }

        resultArray[indexInOutput] = result;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < resultArray.Length; i++ )
        Console.Write(resultArray[i] + " ");
}
```

results in

```
144 96 48 36
```

as you expect.

This way avoids overflow which would happen if you had big numbers in the input array and you were to try to multiply all the numbers and divide by the one not used, e.g. if `inputArray` is

```
{ 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004 }
```